# Temporary Bann Role in Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, roles

I'm basically trying to give members, who say a specific word, a role that takes away reading and writing permissions. The thing i have trouble with is giving the user his roles back.

I tried finding the roles the user has by "message.member.roles.find()" that didn't work sadly. I'm a beginner at this so maybe im missing some easy solution.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.author.bot) {
        // exclude messages from bots
        if ((message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.content.startsWith(prefixPermanent)) && message.content.length > 1) {
            // query commands
            Commands.handleCommand(client, message);
        }
        else if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'bad word' || message.content.toLowerCase() === 'other bad word') {
            const memberroles = message.member.roles.find();
            message.channel.send('Get banned');
            message.member.setRoles(['608002911225643028'])
        setTimeout(() => {
            message.member.setRoles([`memberoles`])
        }, 60000);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing i have trouble with is giving the user his roles back.
>   ...
>   I tried finding the roles the user has by "message.member.roles.find()" that didn't work sadly.

`message.member.roles.find()` only finds the roles that the member currently has.
And in your case, you are trying to add a role back to a member. So you aren't going to find the role from the member.

What you probably want is [`message.guild.roles.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles).
It finds the roles that the guild has.

#### Edit

You had `const memberroles = message.member.roles.find();`
Which only gets one role from members.

Instead, do

```
const memberroles = message.member.roles;
```

It returns an collection of roles which you can input back into `message.member.setRoles()`, like so:

```
...
const memberroles = message.member.roles;
message.channel.send('Get banned');
message.member.setRoles(['608002911225643028'])
setTimeout(() => {
   message.member.setRoles(memberoles)
}, 60000);
...
```

Comment: But lets say:

Member has 3 Roles (RoleA,RoleB,RoleC)

He says the trigger word and gets set to only Having the Role D

After the time runs out i want the bot to give him back the roles he had before getting ''Banned''  How would i do that? :/

Comment: @LonelyChimo Woops, I didn't really understood your question, I edited my answer which probably helps in that case

Comment: @LonelyChimo seems like the method takes in an array of IDs unlike what the doc stated... Could you try `const memberroles = message.member.roles.keys();` instead?

Comment: Oh, so the documentation was correct after all, glad you solved it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

The method `Collection#find()` is not to be used in your situation. That method tries to find the provided ID in the collection.
Instead, simply set `memberroles` to `message.member.roles`.

To set the roles back, do `message.member.setRoles(memberroles)`.